# Matplotlib SOMETIMES updating in tkinter

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

I have a program with a GUI including multiple sliders and a graph. The sliders set parameters of a function, which is supposed to be plotted on the graph. I began by following the directions in http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html, changed from pack to grid, and have experimented ad nauseum. What I have now updates the plot if I move one slider, but not if I move the other slider. I don't see a difference between the two.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from Tkinter import *

domain_min = 1
domain_max = 10
order_min = 0
order_max = 3
fig = Figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=50)

def module(x):
    global domain, order, output_message, fig, a, x_vals, y_vals

    domain = float(domain_slide.get())
    order = int(order_slide.get())

    output_message = 'f(1) = %i\nf(2) = %i\nf(3) = %i\nf(4) = %i\nf(5) = %i\nf(6) = %i\n\
f(7) = %i\nf(8) = %i\nf(9) = %i\nf(10)= %i'%(1**order,2**order,3**order,4**order,5**order,\
                                             6**order,7**order,8**order,9**order,10**order)

    output_message_text.set(output_message)

    x_vals = np.linspace(0,domain,100)
    y_vals = x_vals**order

    a = fig.add_subplot(111)
    a.clear()
    a.plot(x_vals,y_vals,color='blue')

#GUI
root = Tk()

domain_slide = DoubleVar()
order_slide = DoubleVar()
output_message_text = StringVar()

ds = Scale(root, variable = domain_slide, from_ = domain_min, to = domain_max, command = module)
ds.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

o_s = Scale(root, variable = order_slide, from_ = order_min, to = order_max, command = module)
o_s.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

out_message = Message(root, textvariable = output_message_text, width = 300, bg = 'white').grid(column = 0, row = 1, rowspan = 3)


canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=3,row=1)
canvas.show()

label = Label(root)
label.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

What difference does python see in the two sliders? In a more in-depth version of the program, none of the sliders update the plot.

Comment: When you move the slider, is the function being called but the plot doesn't change, or is the function not being called?

Comment: both sliders work fine in your example, but only the right one changes the scale, that is if you change the left slider, and then the right you get the correct output

Comment: The function is called, because the text in the bottom left corner changes. The plot just doesn't change. What I am wondering is how to make the slider on the left also update the plot directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a

```
fig.cavas.draw()
```

to your callback function.

I am not quite sure why it was *ever* redrawing the canvas with out this.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I am not sure either why it worked for some but not others. That is, `fig.canvas.draw`.